# Blackberry custom UI and custom Components

Tags: blackberry

I have been working quite sometime with Blackberry application development but customizing UI and components is something am not very familiar with. I understand that the sublayout, paint, getpreferredWidth, getpreferredHeight methods are to be overridden to customize layouts and components. But still the idea is very vague to me. I am still not able to confidently proceed with the development of UI using these concepts. Can someone explain to me the basics of this? I would like to have a clear understanding from the experts out there.

Answer (score 1):

Best thing to do is look at the source code to the [Advanced UI Components](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-advanced-buttons-fields-and-managers/ta-p/488276) that RIM provides, in conjunction with the [API documentation](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/).